# js event loop y promesas me da error y no especifica cual

Tags: javascript, promesas

necesito que se reproduzca en consola los mensajes en orden correcto con exactamente estas funciones. Creo que esta todo correcto ya que cuando lo pruebo en consola, me da el orden del 1 al 6, pero el test del ejercicio me da error y no especifica cual, tampoco puedo verlo en sources... ¿Alguna sugerencia?:

Indicaciones: Cada constante mensaje debe ser mostrada en con un console.log.

1. Debe haber un `console.log` al principio del código.
2. Debe haber un `console.log` al final del código.
3. Debe haber un `console.log` dentro del callback de un `setTimeout` con un retraso de 0 milisegundos.
4. Debe haber un `console.log` dentro del método `then` de una promesa que se resuelve inmediatamente.
5. Debe haber un `console.log` dentro del callback de un `setTimeout` con un retraso de 0 milisegundos que está dentro del método then de una promesa que se resuelve inmediatamente.
6. Debe haber un `console.log` dentro del metodo then de una promise que se resuelve inmediatamente y que está dentro del callback en un `setTimeout` con un retraso de 0 milisegundos.
7. Debes colocar cada variable de mensaje en el orden correcto para que se muestren los mensajes en el orden indicado: mensaje1, mensaje2, mensaje3, mensaje4, mensaje5 y mensaje6.

```js
const mensaje1 = "Nekgikis VII";
      const mensaje2 = "Faraón de Egipto";
      const mensaje3 = "Hijo de Nekgikis VI";
      const mensaje4 = "Quiere reclutar a los mejores developers";
      const mensaje5 = "¿Quieres ser uno de ellos?";
      const mensaje6 = "Resuelve este problema y envíanos tu solución";

console.log(mensaje1)

setTimeout(() => console.log(mensaje4));

new Promise(resolve => 
    resolve()
).then(() => console.log(mensaje3))

new Promise(resolve => 
    resolve()
).then(() => 
       setTimeout(() => console.log(mensaje6)
))

setTimeout(() => {
    new Promise(resolve => 
        resolve()
    ).then(() => console.log(mensaje5))
})

console.log(mensaje2)
```

Comment: No está claro que estás preguntando. Dices `...cuando lo testeo, me da el orden del 1 al 6 en consola...`, y luego dices `Pero el test me da error`. ¿ Que significa ese `da error` ? ¿ Que test ?

Comment: ese test es publico? si es así, pon la url

Comment: Agrega también el enunciado del asunto, porque no entiendo que es lo que se puede cambiar o no cambiar

Comment: Hola Yebrai, podrías decirnos cual es la salida esperada?. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos.

Comment: Es como si dices:  tengo un código que da 1+1=2, les pongo este ejemplo donde aparece que 1+1=2, pero el test que ustedes no conocen dice que 1+1 no es 2 ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?, además no pueden cambiar el código!!

Comment: Edito el post con las especificaciones para completar el ejercicio... No se si tengo mal quizas alguna forma trabajar con el new Promise...

Comment: Y los mensajes tienen que estar así, pueden estar en un array?

Comment: los mensajes tienen que devolverlos la consola en ese orden, tiene que ser como string y los tiene que devolver el console.log, tal y como indica el ejercicio

Answer (score 1):

Colocas los mensajes en un array y haces un `shift`, ahí te va a respetar el orden

```js
const mensajes = [ "Nekgikis VII", "Faraón de Egipto","Hijo de Nekgikis VI", "Quiere reclutar a los mejores developers", "¿Quieres ser uno de ellos?"
, "Resuelve este problema y envíanos tu solución"];

console.log(mensajes.shift())

setTimeout(() => console.log(mensajes.shift()));

new Promise(resolve => 
    resolve()
).then(() => console.log(mensajes.shift()))

new Promise(resolve => 
    resolve()
).then(() => 
       setTimeout(() => console.log(mensajes.shift())
))

setTimeout(() => {
    new Promise(resolve => 
        resolve()
    ).then(() => console.log(mensajes.shift()))
})

console.log(mensajes.shift())
```

### Edit: Explicación

El ejercicio apunta a **sincronizar** la salida de los mensajes, usando 2 funciones **asíncronas**, ya que tanto `setTimeout` como `new Promise` se ejecutan asíncronamente.

Como javascript tiene un solo hilo, esta extraña situación podría darse en un caso real. Por ejemplo, ejecutar una serie de funciones de procesos pesados de manera asíncrona para no bloquear el hilo (sobre todo la interfaz gráfica), pero esperando que se ejecuten una tras otra en un orden dado, porque cada función depende de los resultados de la anterior.

Para esto, simplemente se pueden usar:

- `await`
- callbacks

**Lo que no se puede hacer:**

No se pueden organizar las funciones asíncronas en un orden específico, esperando que ese orden se respete siempre, esto carece de un sentido profundo.

Entonces, bajo las restricciones impuestas en el ejercicio, que es tener estas 6 funciones que no se pueden cambiar, la opción es atacar los mensajes. En la solución presentada al inicio lo que se hace es poner los mensajes en un `array` e ir vaciándolo como si fuera una `Cola` usando `shift` de esta manera se garantiza el orden de los mensajes sin importar el orden de ejecución de las funciones.

Answer (score 0):

sugiero que manejes las promesas de la siguiente forma:

```js
const mensaje1 = "Nekgikis VII"; 
const mensaje2 = "Faraón de Egipto";
const mensaje3 = "Hijo de Nekgikis VI";

const promesa1 = async () =>{
  try{
    console.log(mensaje1);
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}
const promesa2 = async () =>{
  try{
    console.log(mensaje2);
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}
const ejecutar = async ()=>{
  await promesa1();
  await promesa2();
}
ejecutar();
```

de esta forma, es mas fácil de entender e identificar de una forma más fácil  donde esta el error y como plus, si utilizas funciones asíncronas no es necesario el uso de setTimeout, ya que primero ejecuta promesa1, y hasta que termine ejecuta promesa2